# Centos package naming for FreeIPA?

Tags: centos, centos7, freeipa, packaging

Where can I find information about CentOS package management?

I installed Spacewalk recently and noticed that FreeIPA was listed as ready for an update. The versions are differently named, and the FreeIPA mailing list said it was a CentOS issue. I can't find who/where to ask what the difference in the versions is.

The versions are:

- Installed package `ipa-server-4.2.0-15.el7.centos.3.x86_64`
- Update candidate `ipa-server-4.2.0-15.el7_2.6.x86_64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be other packages affected by this so I think it is a bug in CentOS build system. Looking at the timestamps, this has happened somewhere late November/early December 2015. I've talked to KB and CentOS people are looking into the issue. I imagine people will rebuild all the affected packages once the core of the issue will be found.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the `centos` bit in a package name means that it's a package from which CentOS has removed some Red Hat branding, artwork or other intellectual property. Someone appears to have forgotten to keep the tag on this package.